# Adding a fragment to main activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm following the Android Udacity Course and it's out dated so I tried to update it my self by adding a fragment manually to the main activity.
This code builds fine but crashes when the app is started giving me a veeery long error in the android monitor.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container,new PHFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class PHFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

XML
fragment_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.athomield.mysunshine.MainActivity"
    android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_forecast"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</FrameLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.athomield.mysunshine.MainActivity"
    android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false">

</FrameLayout>
```

list_itemm_forecast.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    >
</TextView>
```

LOG

06-23 11:23:02.878 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.athomield.mysunshine-1/lib/x86
06-23 11:23:06.230 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.athomield.mysunshine-1/lib/x86
06-23 11:23:06.408 3095-3105/com.example.athomield.mysunshine W/art: Suspending all threads took: 58.067ms
06-23 11:23:06.417 3095-3105/com.example.athomield.mysunshine I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 13182(1591KB) AllocSpace objects, 9(208KB) LOS objects, 73% free, 991KB/3MB, paused 64.383ms total 75.476ms
06-23 11:23:06.509 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-23 11:23:06.685 3095-3101/com.example.athomield.mysunshine W/art: Suspending all threads took: 29.223ms
06-23 11:23:06.772 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f0b0054 (com.example.athomield.mysunshine:id/container) for fragment PHFragment{ccbb2d0 #0 id=0x7f0b0054}
06-23 11:23:06.772 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager: Activity state:
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:   Local FragmentActivity b704817 State:
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:     mCreated=falsemResumed=false mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:     mLoadersStarted=false
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:   FragmentManager misc state:
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:     mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@16b2c9
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:     mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@16b2c9
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:     mCurState=1 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:   View Hierarchy:
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:     com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4998dce V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:       android.widget.LinearLayout{9ea54ef V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:         android.view.ViewStub{e812bfc G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #10203a9 android:id/action_mode_bar_stub}
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:         android.widget.FrameLayout{94eb285 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:           android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout{8c4b8da V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0043 app:id/decor_content_parent}
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:             android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout{eb1510b V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020002 android:id/content}
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:               android.widget.RelativeLayout{1b30be8 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:                 android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{44cf201 VFED..C. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0055 app:id/button}
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:                 android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{44588a6 VFED..C. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0056 app:id/button2}
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:             android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer{7a1f2e7 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0044 app:id/action_bar_container}
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:               android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar{da0fe94 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0045 app:id/action_bar}
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:                 android.widget.TextView{595ad3d V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0}
06-23 11:23:06.773 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/FragmentManager:               android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView{5b18932 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0046 app:id/action_context_bar}
06-23 11:23:06.774 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

```
                                                                            --------- beginning of crash
```

06-23 11:23:06.774 3095-3095/com.example.athomield.mysunshine E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.athomield.mysunshine, PID: 3095
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.athomield.mysunshine/com.example.athomield.mysunshine.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b0054 (com.example.athomield.mysunshine:id/container) for fragment PHFragment{ccbb2d0 #0 id=0x7f0b0054}
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b0054 (com.example.athomield.mysunshine:id/container) for fragment PHFragment{ccbb2d0 #0 id=0x7f0b0054}
                                                                                    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:965)
                                                                                    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
                                                                                    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
                                                                                    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
                                                                                    at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6252)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: You should include here the error. It'll be hard to help you without it.

Comment: You are probably using the wrong type of `FragmentManager` for `AppCompatActivity`. Use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead. Note that if you are not using the support version of `Fragment` you will need to change that as well.

Comment: this is the error part

Comment: @Emmanuel even the getSupportFragmentManager() has the same results.

Comment: Please post your `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: please note that removing getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container,new PHFragment()).commit();  stops the problem.

Comment: It can't find your `container` `FrameLayout` for the `FragmentTransaction`. Make certain that the `activity_main` layout you've posted is really what is being used for `MainActivity`. If it is, then try cleaning/rebuilding your project.

Comment: @MikeM. How it wouldn't find the container but still builds without errors ?The problem is there when the app launches. Cleaning and rebuilding the project unfortunately has no effect.

Comment: Also for some reason when I omit the  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container,new PHFragment()).commit();
i have two buttons appearing on main activity that i put earlier but deleted them and they are still showing.

Comment: I tried rebuild/clean, deleting the build folder and still there.

Comment: The project will compile just fine as long as you have a `container` ID somewhere in it. It just can't find a `View` for that ID in `MainActivity`'s `View` hierarchy. If that really is your current `activity_main`, and some phantom `Button`s appear that are no longer there when you remove the `FragmentTransaction`, then uninstall/reinstall your app, restart your IDE, reboot the device/emulator, clean/rebuild again, etc. Something's just not caught up with your current code and layouts.

Answer (score 5):

Here you can go like this:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
.....
  private FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
  private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
.....

  mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new PhfFragment());
    mFragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged.

Comment: This have the same results.

Answer (score 3):

you should use`getSupportFragmentManager` instead. That should resolve your issue.

Update: After seeing your crash report it is more apparent. Your issue is not with `supportFragementManager`. Your issue is with the id to inflate your fragment. User `R.id.fragment_container` when you are adding the fragment. You need to add a `viewgroup` rather than layout file name when you want to add fragment dynamically.
`R.id.fragment_container` viewgroup must be present in your main activity's layout. For e.g. it can be Another FrameLayout within your activity's FrameLayout.
So while loading fragment your code should be:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_containe,new PHFragment()).commit();
```

source :[Android developer Fragments link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: "That should resolve your issue." - You sure about that? Just using the regular `FragmentManager` with a regular `Fragment` won't cause a crash by itself.

Comment: Hi, Akshay : this is giving me the same results.

Comment: @MikeM. Well I don't know what is causing his crash so you got me there. But in the past I had issues with using standard `FragmentManager` (can't remember exact since it has been a while). However once I switched to support fragmentManager it worked finel

Comment: @Athomield when you're inflating your fragment use `R.id.listview_forecast` instead of `R.id.container` . Your container is not in fragment viewgroup ,

Comment: This is becoming so overwhelming, Still same problem

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer is just not correct. The ID passed to `FragmentTransaction#add()` - or any other `FragmentTransaction` action method - needs to be the ID for the `ViewGroup` that will hold the `Fragment`, not a `ViewGroup` in the `Fragment`'s own layout.

Comment: @MikeM. yes you're right. I somehow miss read `R.id.listview_forecast` and though it is part of main activity.  I have now corrected the answer. Sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that you import *support.v4.app.fragment* and not *android.fragment* and then call *getSupportFragmentManager* OR upgrade your min SDK in the build gradle file if you want to use the second option.

Comment: using  import support.v4.app.fragment and getSupportFragmentManager has the same result